# Clamp Rectangle inside larger Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Lets say I have an XNA Rectangle with

```
X = 0, Y = 0, Width = 25, Height = 25.
```

What I want is a method to clamp another rectangle inside, so that the smaller rectangle never 'leaves' the bounds of the larger one.

For example, if I make a new Rectangle with:

```
X = 23, Y = 20, Width = 10, Height = 10,
```

I want the method to return a Rectangle with:

```
X = 23, Y = 20, Width = 2, Height = 5.
```

Also, if I make a new Rectangle with:

```
X = -8, Y = 8, Width = 10, = 10,
```

I want the method to return a Rectangle with:

```
X = 0, Y = 8, Width = 2, Height = 10.
```

---

In the meanwhile I got the clamping to work. Still, its a bulk of ugly code, so the new question is, how can I simplify this?

```
if (SelectionRectangle.X < 0)
        {
            SelectionRectangle.Width = SelectionRectangle.Width + SelectionRectangle.X;
            SelectionRectangle.X = 0;
        }
        if (SelectionRectangle.X + SelectionRectangle.Width > tileset.Width)
        {
            if (SelectionRectangle.X > tileset.Width)
            {
                SelectionRectangle.X = tileset.Width;
                SelectionRectangle.Width = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectionRectangle.Width = tileset.Width - SelectionRectangle.X;
            }
        }
        if (SelectionRectangle.Y < 0)
        {
            SelectionRectangle.Height = SelectionRectangle.Height + SelectionRectangle.Y;
            SelectionRectangle.Y = 0;
        }
        if (SelectionRectangle.Y + SelectionRectangle.Height > tileset.Height)
        {
            if (SelectionRectangle.Y > tileset.Height)
            {
                SelectionRectangle.Y = tileset.Height;
                SelectionRectangle.Height = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectionRectangle.Height = tileset.Height - SelectionRectangle.Y;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? The code you wrote, why didnt it work, what was your problem?

Comment: can you please show us where you are applying the clamp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this just [`Rectangle.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx)?

> Creates a Rectangle defining the area where one rectangle overlaps another rectangle.

If the smaller rectangle is entirely within the larger rectangle, then the intersection will be the same as the smaller rectangle. If the smaller rectangle extends outside of the larger rectangle, that portion will not be returned.

Comment: Actually, I've overlooked this method for the past two years. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    Rectangle clamp(Rectangle smaller, Rectangle larger)
    {
        Rectangle ret;
        ret.X = Math.Max(smaller.X, larger.X);
        ret.Y = Math.Max(smaller.Y, larger.Y);
        ret.Width = Math.Min(smaller.X + smaller.Width, larger.X + larger.Width) - ret.X;
        ret.Height = Math.Min(smaller.Y + smaller.Height, larger.Y + larger.Height) - ret.Y;
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ClampRectangle(Rectangle outside, Rectangle inside) {
    if(inside.left < outside.left) {
        inside.width -= outside.left - inside.left;
        inside.left = outside.left
    }
    if(inside.right > outside.right) {
        inside.width -= inside.right - outside.right;
    }
    if(inside.top < outside.top) {
        inside.height -= outside.top - inside.top;
        inside.top = outside.top;
    }
    if(inside.bottom > outside.bottom) {
        inside.height -= inside.height - outside.height;
    }
}
```

I just typed the code here, so check for spelling errors.
I'm not sure if the properties are with capitals or not (height/Height ...)

Comment: But what if inside.Right = 23, outside.Right = 25, and inside.Width = say, 15?

Comment: The 'right' = left border + width, so if the inside.Right < outside.Right it means that the inner Rectangle is inside the outer Rectangle